# awk - print last field $NF of array

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

is any chance how to print - lets say example:

A/b/c/d/e/f A B C D E F G|H|I|J|

I would like to split fields to array and print:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{split($1,a,"/"); split($3,b,"|"); print a[LAST_FIELD??],$1,$2,$3,b[1],b[2]}' input
```

the result should be:

```
f A B C g H I
```

I am not sure how to define "LAST_FIELD" in my array. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split` returns the number of elements, so you can use that:

```
n = split($1,a,"/")
```

then:

```
print a[n]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{lena=split($1,a,"/"); split($NF,b,"|");
      print a[lena],$2,$3,$4,b[1],b[2],b[3]}' file

f   A   B   C   G   H   I
```